# CompizConfig Manager missing Burn and Explode effects

Tags: compiz

My `ccsm` didnt have the option to set the window burn and explode. How can I enable this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the `compiz-fusion-plugins-extra` installed. A lot of the Animations were moved to the plugins-extra package.

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
```

Comment: @Macro: I cannot find it either, after the extra package is installed

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find "Burn" even after installing `compiz-fusion-plugins-extra` make sure your "Animation add-on" option is selected, it is exactly next to "animation"

In simple words:

1. open `ccsm`
2. Check **Animation add-on** checkbox
3. open **animation** ... and do as suggested